# Why is QNX 2 partitions an example of non-QNX partition?

Tags: filesystems, qnx

I was going through the '''chkfsys''', and I came across the statement 
'''The chkfsys utility doesn't operate on disk partitions containing non-QNX filesystems (e.g. DOS partitions, QNX 2 partitions)'''.
Can anybody explain why even though its not QNX partition, why is it named as 'QNX-2' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just poor wording in the utility.  The file system form used int QNX 2 is entirely incompatible with QNX 4 and onwards.   Initially the new file system was called the QNX 4 Filesystem, and the only support for the qnx2 one was a utility which permitted copying files from it.

Unlike a unix-inspired file system, the QNX/2 intermingled meta-data with data, so each extent formed a doubly linked list.  Sadly, this made it hard to predict read sizes, as a single sector extent would be a little smaller than a sector.  On the positive side, recovery from a wounded disk was much more effective since there was no fat/inode/... table to rely upon.